# How to access another web-page within index page in flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The problem I'm facing is to access a web page within the index page, registration page to be precise, using flask. While trying to access register.html via index.html using the code below I get 404 Not Found Error.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_wtf import Form #instead of flask.ext.wtf use flask_wtf
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Comment: Can you post the part of `index.html` template that tries to access `register.html`?

Comment: <a href="register.html"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register Now!</a>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running your app before your `register` route gets defined.

Move the actual run directive to the very bottom right after your views are defined and routes registered so it becomes something like this:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_wtf import Form #instead of flask.ext.wtf use flask_wtf
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html',methods=['GET','POST'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: From your comment under original question, it looks like you are trying to access your register route via `register.html` that is not correct, since you are defining it as just being `/register` <- this should be you ahref, as in `<a href="/register">Register Now!</a>`. Please also have a look through flask quickstart here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/